# Good practice to write common function in golang

Tags: go

I'm using golang to writer a web server application.

Need to use a very common database query function `findUserByEmail(DB gorm.DB, email string )` in several controllers in the same package.

not sure where should I declare this function so that I don't need to copy this code in every controller when I need it.

I can make it as `FindUserByEmail(DB gorm.DB, email string )` in one of the controller. so that I could use it in any other contollers. but that seems not a good practice?

Comment: A Go package is one directory with one or more files. At compile time, the compiler merges all the files for a package. A function can appear in one and only one of these files. What is your question exactly?

Comment: thx @peterSO, I mean I want to define a function in one place and call it in many other controllers. where should I declare this function?

Comment: Show us an example of how you defined the function multiple times in the package and we will tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: "A [Go] function lets us wrap up a sequence of statements as a unit that can be called from elsewhere in a program, perhaps multiple times." The Go Programming Language, Alan A. A. Donovan and Brian W. Kernighan.

Comment: "where should I declare this function" It does not matter. Whatever fits your needs best.

Comment: If you are struggling with dependency issues (like, you do not want to depend on implementations) then your code might be a candidate for dependency injection.  Depend on a package that defines interfaces, and have implementations bound at runtime with your favorite DI injector (e.g. https://github.com/jwells131313/dargo)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a seperate package for your database functions called db for example.
create a folder in your project named db and put all codes there.

```
package db

FindUserByEmail(DB gorm.DB, email string ) {
...
}
```

When you need it you can access the package like this :

```
import "myproject/db"

db.FindUserByEmail(gorm,"test@gmail.com")
```

Comment: @Hank If this answer helped you please accept it, thanks.